# saving soap ui results of test with xml

Tags: testing, soapui

is it possible to save results of run tests in SOAP UI, including xml's of used requests and replies?

i would like to export it and send it to customer, but when i looked i couldn't find no such option

regards,

Vercy

Answer (score 0):

Look in the project file XML, it's all in there. Optionally you can copy/paste any request into a text editor.

Comment: request maybe yes, but response"

Comment: If you want responses, create a mock service, make mock responses, then copy/paste real responses into the mock responses, and there you go. They'll be preserved within the project now.

Answer (score 0):

Right-click in the XML editor of the request/response and select "Save as.." ;-)

Comment: so i assume there is no possiblity to save it as a whole entity?